# Apache authentication against custom web service

Tags: apache-2.4, authentication, reverse-proxy, mod-auth

I would like to have apache that forwards the call to an internal service (a django app) that returns a True/False (and some parameters maybe) if the user is valid or not. This before forwarding the request to the service that should processes it. 
Is this possible?

I checked the mods and the one similar to what i would like to do are

- the [mod for the db](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_dbd.html)
- and the [django auth implementation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/apache-auth/)

The fact is that both uses standard way to do it, such as a query on a table or a Django authorization made with username and password.

In my case I've to satisfy more broad cases, such as a possible login with ID/Key or Oauth or other things. For example i could also add the user to   to a cache so at the second login I can get the value from there.

My idea for this would be that Apache forwards a call to an internal system `https://localhost/validate` that returns a validation value.

Is this possible?

(is this possible with other webserver/reverse proxies?)

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for a similar thing. 
This could help you : https://github.com/phokz/mod-auth-external/tree/master/mod_authnz_external

Comment: could you provide more text about that lib, as you already use it, please :)